# How can I include resources from other modules in multiple module maven app?

Tags: java, maven

I have a multiple module maven project. The project tree goes like this:

```
|parent project
|-> core app 
|-> web app
```

web app has a dependency to core app, so core app is packed to a jar file and included in lib directory of the web app when the project is compiled and packed to a war file.

The source looks like this:

[image]

And the final web-app looks like this:

[image]

As you can see multi-core.jar file is included in the lib directory. But where did 2.png go? Is there any way to include it in the war file?

Comment: Your 2.png file is inside your multi-core*.jar When you define a multi module project whatever is not a war module will be inside a jar. To see it you can get the multi-core*.jar file and turn it in a zip file and open it. You will see your file inside the resources folder. Let me know if it helps you!

Comment: Logically yes, your 2.png resource should be in the jar file and as mentioned by @JorgeCampos kindly see inside your jar and if it's not there, let us know.

Comment: How should I reach that image from a servlet in web module?

Comment: somthing similar like this `Classname.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/2.png")`